# How to write a Streaming Structured Stream into Hive directly?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-structured-streaming

I want to achieve something like this :

```scala
df.writeStream
.saveAsTable("dbname.tablename")
.format("parquet")
.option("path", "/user/hive/warehouse/abc/")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/checkpoint_path") 
.outputMode("append")
.start()
```

I am open to suggestions. I know Kafka Connect could be one of the options but how to achieve this using Spark. A possible workaround may be what I am looking for.
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking at. Any workaround must be appreciated. But I'll still give an upvote for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Spark Structured Streaming does **not** support writing the result of a streaming query to a Hive table directly. You must write to paths.

For 2.4 they say try foreachBatch, but I have not tried it.